# MYSQL - how to get previous row value if current value is zero

Tags: mysql

I have a table called **value_record** like below

```
id | record_id | value | serverTime
1  |     20    |   0   |  2016-04-19 04:51:16
2  |     20    |   0   |  2016-04-19 04:40:19
3  |     20    |   0   |  2016-04-19 04:27:34
4  |     20    |   70  |  2016-04-19 04:14:24
5  |     20    |   50  |  2016-04-19 04:02:21
```

..

```
select value from value_record
where record_id in(20) 
order by serverTime desc limit 1;
```

output :

```
0
```

but expected output is:

```
70
```

it means if current value is zero then query go back previous row where not zero and display the non zero value.

How to achieve this in mysql?

Comment: using that query you get multiple output

Comment: @SanoojT sorry check now updated question

Comment: do you need the latest record greater than `0`, Or you need recent record with the `value` column from another record greater than '0' ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to filter values different than 0 and you don't need `IN` clause:

```
SELECT
    `value`
FROM
    value_record
WHERE
    record_id = 20
    AND `value` > 0
ORDER BY
    serverTime DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT value 
FROM value_record 
WHERE record_id IN(20) 
AND value > 0 
ORDER BY serverTime LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @Joop Eggen :Yes, there is no DESC, because the question didn't ask to sort it before getting edited. 
Anyway it help out was more important.